# How do I construct my action method for a specific route Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes I'm trying to create to use like

> www.mysite.com/Rate/Student/Event/123
>
> www.mysite.com/Rate/Teacher/Event/1234

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Rate",
    url: "Rate/Student/Event/{id}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Rate",
    url: "Rate/Teacher/Event/{id}"
);
```

How do I construct the action methods?

Here is what I have in my Rate controller

```
public ActionResult Student(int id)
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Teacher(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have set up routing to match the URL, but you haven't told MVC where to send the request. MapRoute works by using *route values*, which can either be defaulted to specific values or passed through the URL. But, you are doing neither.

> **NOTE:** The `controller` and `action` route values are required in MVC.

### Option 1: add default route values.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Rate",
        url: "Rate/Student/Event/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Rate", action = "Student" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Rate",
        url: "Rate/Teacher/Event/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Rate", action = "Teacher" }
    );
```

### Option 2: pass the route values through the URL.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Rate",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/Event/{id}"
    );
```